# following python flow of execution when project is run

Tags: python, python-3.x, trace, pdb

I want to start on an open source project.
is there a way i could follow the flow of execution of code in python when its run.
Using `sys.set_trace()` i am able to follow the trace of a code blocks in a script. I want to bump this up to bigger projects lets say for example a django app. 
a simple example given the command `python3 manage.py runserver` when run with "trace" - *an imaginery tool* 
`trace python3 manage.py runserver` would listen for function and method calls from in project after the command and maybe print them out somewhere.
What would be the best way to go about implementing this.
my idea is creating a virtual box like docker where i would listen for any python calls.
Does anyone have a better way or input to help me on this
i would highly appreciate it

Comment: You might (or might not, depending on your experience) be surprised how much the computer is doing when you start tracing everything.  I propose to insert print statements at vital points (using a special function instead of directly `print` so that you can switch it off quickly).  You can also add a special self-written decorator to functions and methods to make them print their enter and leave events.

Comment: Using `sys.settrace()` looks like the obviuos way. What is your actual issue?

Comment: **I just realized there actually is a python command called trace
that exactly that
https://pymotw.com/2/trace/**